# How to access domain classes from a custom plugin to another?

Tags: grails, groovy

I am currently working on grails project. I have created eight different plugins. Each having a set of Domain classes and other stuffs. Now, from one of my plugins, a certain Domain class needs to access a domain class from the other plugin. How will I do that? Do I have to import the domain classes from the other plugin? If so, how? or Shall I do that in BuildConfig.groovy?

Please help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple make the plugin that need other plugin domains dependent from it in buildconfig

```
//buildConfig of plugins need other plugin domains

grails.project.dependency.plugins{
   ...
   compile ':<other-plugin-name>:<other-plugin-version>'
   ...
}
```

The simply import the right package where you need it.

If you are constantly working on the depended plugin and you don't want to repackage it constantly you can connect it using grails.plugin.location instead of grails.project.dependency.plugins.

in buildConfig add

```
grails.plugin.location.'other-plugin-name' = "/path/to/other/plugin/folder"
```

Comment: Hi my question is slightly different but How to access domain classes of Main project inside the custom plugin? This is reverse of the above question.

Comment: @Chetan, I don't think that's possible. You might need to reorganise your app if you find you need to access your main class from your plugin.

Comment: To add to @Cyntech's answer, the type of reorganization that can happen is to move all your main application's domain classes into a plugin. This is actually pretty straightforward, and then you can use the layout of plugin->plugin dependencies. Reference http://www.bobbywarner.com/2011/06/21/grails-setup/